# Expanding/Breaking down a for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, nchar

```
`y <- c()

for( position in c("cannon","jackson","benford","paws","moxie") ) {
n <- nchar(position)
y[position] <- letters[n]
}

y

n
```

What I am essentially trying to do is write the code that is behind the scenes of this for loop but I am running into issues as to where to go with it. What would this for loop expanded look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `position <- "cannon"`

   - `n <- nchar(position)` → `n <- nchar("cannon")` → `n <- 6`
   - `y[position] <- letters[n]` → `y["cannon"] <- letters[6]` → `j["cannon"] <- "f"`
2. `position <- "jackson"`

   - `n <- nchar(position)` → `n <- nchar("jackson")` → `n <- 7`
   - `y[position] <- letters[n]` → `y["jackson"] <- letters[7]` → `j["jackson"] <- "g"`

etc